# How to include part of an external git hash as text inside a document?

Tags: xetex, xstring, revision-control, git

*This is my first time asking a question on a site like this. Please tell me if I should do something differently, thanks!*

I want to include a short version of the latest commit hash from git as a text string in a (Xe)LaTeX document. How do I do that?

I am able to include the full hash simply with:

```
\input{.git/ORIG_HEAD}
```

But I am not able to figure out how to shorten down the hash with the `xstring` package when I am getting the string from a macro. What I currently have is this:

```
\usepackage{xstring}

\expandarg %% Not at all sure about this command
\StrLeft{\input{.git/ORIG_HEAD}}{8}[\gitrevision]

I would prefer \gitrevision\ to be a short hash.
```

A fix for the above code would be most appreciated, as the code is constructed from my way of thinking. Yes, I have RTFM, but it is in my opinion lacking in the department of plain down-to-earth usage examples.

Of course, a completely different (working) solution is also welcome!

A final note, I would easily be able to do all this with an external `bash` script and/or with the `\write18` macro, but I have put an arbitrary limit on myself to only rely on TeX in this case. Otherwise I will never learn more. Many thanks for taking the time to read this question!

Comment: Not exactly answering your question, but have you seen the [`gitinfo`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gitinfo) package?

Comment: Yes, with `gitinfo` I can get the desired result. But I would like to set up a workflow where scripts (git hooks included) aren’t needed. And it seems to me that the `xstring` solution should work, just that I am missing some crucial understanding of TeX’s grammar or inner workings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The more general solution to including `git` metadata in documents is the `gitinfo2` package (which supersedes `gitinfo` that I mentioned in a comment). Having set that up, `\gitAbbrevHash` gives you a seven character hash.

---

There may be more elegant ways of achieving this, but as a workaround you can use the `catchfile` package to store the full hash in a macro, and use this macro in `\StrLeft`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\CatchFileDef{\HEAD}{.git/refs/heads/master}{}
\newcommand{\gitrevision}{%
  \StrLeft{\HEAD}{7}%
}

\begin{document}

Long: \HEAD

Short: \gitrevision
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know this was asked almost three years ago, but I came across the question again, and thought I'd try find a solution.

Comment: Thank you, this is an acceptable, working solution for my original question. I may even find some use of it today, I think. Thanks for taking the time coming back to this.

Comment: On Windows `\CatchFileDef` seem neither to work with files without extensions (like `master`)  nor relative paths beginning with `.` (like the `.git` folder).  Is there an alternative to `\CatchFileDef` whose file path input is more permissive?

Comment: @alx9r No idea, I suggest asking a new question.